# How to assign queues to a worker in resque-pool using wildcard characters?

Tags: resque

I know `'*':1` creates a worker to work on all queues and `'q1,q2':1` on queues `q1` and `q2`, but is there a way to assign queues using something like `queue_*` instead of specifying the full name of queue? Thanks!